# Swapping a key with a value in a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to validate if a textbox contains a key contained in a dictionary and if so, replace it with the associated value without losing the rest of the text in it. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

```
string s = txtID.Text;
if (s.StartsWith("S"))
{
    SMS s1 = new SMS();

    if (txtSender.Text.StartsWith("+") && txtSender.Text.Length.Equals(14))
    {
        s1.id = txtID.Text;
        s1.setCharacterLimit();
        s1.datereceived = Convert.ToInt32(txtDate.Text);
        s1.MessageBody = txtMessage.Text;
        foreach (string k in data.Keys)
        {
            foreach (string v in data.Values)
            {
                if (data.ContainsKey(s1.MessageBody))
                {
                    txtMessage.Text.Replace(k, v);
                }
            }
        }
        s1.Sender = txtSender.Text;
        if (s1.MessageBody.Length < s1.CharacterLimit)
        {
            lsttest.Items.Add(s1.id);
            lsttest.Items.Add(s1.datereceived);
            lsttest.Items.Add(s1.MessageBody);
            lsttest.Items.Add(s1.Sender);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This message was not accepted");
        txtSender.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
txtMessage.Text.Replace(k, v);
```

Should probably be:

```
txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text.Replace(k, v);
```

Comment: This only returns the first value in v for some reason.

Comment: @Liam that's because of the double foreach loops you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.  One is that you are not setting the result of `Replace`.  Second the double `foreach` loops are going to result in a lot of unneeded looping and will potentially do the wrong replacement.  Also I assume you actually want to set the `s1.MessageBody` and not the original `txtMessage.Text` in which case I don't think you even need to use `Replace`.

Replace this

```
foreach(string k in data.Keys)
foreach(string v in data.Values)
{
    if(data.ContainsKey(s1.MessageBody))
    {
        txtMessage.Text.Replace(k, v);
    }
}
```

With this

```
if(data.ContainsKey(s1.MessageBody))
{
    s1.MessageBody = data[s1.MessageBody];
}
```

**EDIT**

It sounds like what you actually want to do is the following instead.

```
foreach(var kvp in data)
{
    s1.MessageBody = s1.MessageBody.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Instead of a `Dictionary<string, string>` you could just use a `List<Tuple<string, string>>`, but it wouldn't make a very big difference.  You just don't get any of the benefits of a dictionary for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, that got me over the first hurdle but only works if there is nothing else in the string but the key.

Comment: @Liam Yes, dictionary lookups are designed to look up keys based on equality.  If that's not the operation that you want, then you shouldn't be using a `Dictionary` in the first place.

Comment: Any suggestion on a better data structure for that problem?

Comment: @Liam could you give an example of what values are in your dictionary and the value of the textbox and exactly what how you expect it to change the value.  Basically we need to know if you are trying to replace each occurrence of each key in the text box with the corresponding value.

Comment: The keys in the dictionary are textspeak such as brb with the value being be right back and the intended input into the textbox is the average text message which includes textspeak but is not entirely textspeak. So yes, each occurrence of key with the corresponding value.

Comment: @Liam OK, I've edited my answer with what I think you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you need to change

```
txtMessage.Text.Replace(k, v);
```

with

```
txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text.Replace(k, v);
```

But it seems that you have some problems with your code. The double iteration through firstly the keys and then the values of the dictionary seems to be for no purpose. You can do it like this:

```
string value = "";
if (data.TryGetValue(s1.MessageBody, out value))
{
    txtMessage.Text = txtMessage.Text.Replace(s1.MessageBody, value);
}
```